# getting a list of matching nodes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

Currently I've determined that two graphs are isomorphic (by my definition) and I would like a list of the nodes that were matched during is_isomorphic(). Is there a function to do this?

Should mention that I'm using networkx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can retrieve the isomorphic mapping between the two graphs. will that do? see [here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.isomorphism.vf2.html).

```
>>> from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism
>>> G1 = nx.path_graph(4)
>>> G2 = nx.path_graph(4)
>>> GM = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G1,G2)
>>> GM.is_isomorphic()
True
>>> GM.mapping
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```